# how to upload and download images to ftp server in flutter?

Tags: flutter, ftp

please help me to downloading and uploading operation to a ftp server in flutter camera Application. which package using for this operation?

Comment: Did you try this package: https://pub.dev/packages/ftpconnect ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Socket .

```
dependencies:
  web_socket_channel: ^2.0.0
```

---

```
import 'package:web_socket_channel/io.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/status.dart' as status;

    void main() {
      final channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect('ws://localhost:1234');
    
      channel.stream.listen((message) {
        channel.sink.add('received!');
        channel.sink.close(status.goingAway);
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did is edit the `android/app/androidmanifest.xml` and add:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
```

Also add this package your `pubspec.yaml`:

```
dependencies:
  ftpconnect: ^1.0.0
```